# Block sbatch until resource allocation

Tags: slurm

Is it possible to block a `sbatch` until resources are allocated? I know it's got a `--wait` option but I believe that blocks `sbatch` until all the commands are finished on the allocated node(s). I'm also aware that `salloc` and `srun` exist but I'm very keen on using sbatch's `--wrap` option which `srun` and `salloc` don't support.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74112557/1763614) to a similar question it could offer a solution with a small modification in the code